# Make vlcj screen black java

Tags: java, screen, vlcj

im making a quiz for a project and when someone wants to answer the question on a video piece, i need to pause the video and make the screen black so other people can't watch more of the video.

Pausing works perfectly, but is there any way how i can make the screen black? I've tried changing it's brightness but that isn't working.

This is what my run/pause/resume functions look like :

```
/**
 * Run the media player
 */
public void run(){
    ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediaPath);
}

/**
 * Pause the media player 
 */
public void pause() {
    ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().pause();

}

public void resume() {

    ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().play();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just dont render the video anymore.

Comment: But when the answer is wrong i need to play the video from the moment where i paused it and show it...

Comment: Set a boolean paused and in the render loop check for !paused, so if the answer is wrong you can set paused to false and resume the video

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you mean. What you mean with render loop? The video starts by itself, and to pause it you have to click a button, same for resuming.

Comment: Oh, so there is no render loop. Is there something like ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().hide() or .setActive(boolean active) .setShown() or something like that?

Comment: No not really, i've found a temporary solution where i minimalize the jframe, and open it again when it's resumed.

Comment: So I took a look at the at the documentation for it and I found the method .setGamma(float gamma), so maybe setGamma(0.01f) would work?

Comment: No, that isn't working aswell...

Comment: Use a CardLayout, one for the video, one for a black JPanel, switch between the two as needed.